# BASH: How to send params & data to a process on STDIN

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, password-protection

I'm scripting a call to curl, you can enter the password & parameters via STDIN (keep password off the cmd line).

I also need to send POST data on STDIN (large amount of data that won't fit on the cmd line).

So, from a command line I can successfully do this by:

```
> curl -K --data-binary @- -other_non-pw_params
> -u "username:password"
> <User types ctrl-d>
> lots_of_post_data
> lots_of_post_data
> <User types ctrl-d>
> <User types ctrl-d>
```

Now... I'm trying to do that in a BASH script...

Wishful-thinking Psudo-code:

```
{ echo '-u "username:password"'
  echo <ctrl-d>    |   cat dev/null   |   ^D
  echo lots_of_post_data
  echo lots_of_post_data
} | curl -K --data-binary @- -other_non-pw_params
```

Comment: You're not far off... I think all you need to change is <ctrl-d> to the proper escape sequence, etc. Have you tried that?

Comment: No idea what escape sequence I'd use.

Comment: The echo man page tells you which escape sequences it supports. But I think Ignacio's answer is right--Bash can't "close" STDOUT, which is really what you need. You probably need something more sophisticated than a shell script if you need to send a Ctrl-D/EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! There's a curl specific solution to this.

You pass all of the parameters on STDIN, and leave --data-binary @- (or it's equivalent) to the end, then everything after it is accepted as data input. Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ echo '--basic'
  echo '--compress'
  echo '--url "https://your_website"'
  echo '-u "username:password"'
  echo '--data-binary @-'
  echo 'lots_of_post_data'
  echo 'lots_of_post_data'
} | curl --config -
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a "here document":

```
curl --config - <<EOF
--basic
...
EOF
```

Comment: Nice idea, but does this work if those two lines "echo 'lots_of_post_data'" are replaced with loops to populate the data?

Comment: Ah, no. In that case, your solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to simulate a EOF as in Ctrl-D in the terminal save to stop sending data to the stream altogether. You will need to find a different way of doing this, perhaps by writing a script in a more capable language.